# Excel VBA charts changing source

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with 69 charts linked to another excel file, and I want to change the source of all charts to a Sheet in my current file, but I couldn't do it. Does anyone know how to? Thanks!

Comment: The cells are exactly the same, I just need to change the source from the other flie to the sheet in my current file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your chart,
2. Choose 'Select Data'.
3. In chart data range at the top, enter:

   =[PathTo.xlsx]Sheet[N]![Range]

Where:

> *[PathTo.xlsx]* = Path to your remote file
>
> *Sheet[N]* = Sheet Name
>
> *[Range]* = Cell range to be charted.

For example:

```
=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$13
```

Hope that helps!